# ListView change background of selected item

Tags: android, listview, background, selector

I want to set the currently clicked item to a different colour which I have implemented as this.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(StaggeredGridView parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked Position "+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("Clicked","Clicked Position "+position+" Content "+contentList.get(position));
    if(prevSelected !=null)
    {
        prevSelected.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));

    }
    prevSelected = view;
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_pressed_holo_light);
    selectedPosition = position;
}
```

Now the problem I am facing is that if this selected view is recycled in getView() all those views also have this same background. If I change their background then the background of this view also changes. Anyone has a solution to this.

Comment: use a selector for this puspose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I've ended up with in my getView().

```
            if (convertView != null){
            // If the selected view is used somewhere else
            if (convertView.equals(prevSelected) && position != selectedPosition)
            {
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
                Log.d("Yup", "Changing color");
                Log.d("Yup", position + "  " + selectedPosition);
            }
            // If the selected view is redrawn and the recycled view is not
            // the same view again
            else if (position == selectedPosition && !convertView.equals(prevSelected))
            {
                // Make all other views if any which were prev selected
                // white
                prevSelected.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
                prevSelected = convertView;
                convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_pressed_holo_light);
                Log.d("Yup", "Setting pressed color");
                Log.d("Yup", position + "  " + selectedPosition);
            }
            // The case where pos == selected pos and same view was used
            // again.Need to set it to that colour as it could have been
            // changed in the first condition
            else if(position == selectedPosition && convertView.equals(prevSelected))
            {
                prevSelected = convertView;
                convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_pressed_holo_light);
                Log.d("Yup!", "Setting that view colour");
                Log.d("Yup!", position + "  " + selectedPosition);
            }
            }
```

Comment: i have a query do u help

Comment: if i use this code `onItemclickListner` will work properly or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the required background also in `getView()` method everything will work fine ;)
Just put in your `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method:

```
if (convertView != null){
    if (position == selectedPosition) {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
    } else {
        convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_pressed_holo_light);
    }
}
```

Comment: however this is not. the way you should follow, instead you should add view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.some_state_list_drawable)

Comment: you are right, but that was not the point. Important is to set the background also in `getView()` method. When it comes to how to do it I just copied the code that Rajul is using to set the background for both selected and not selected item

Comment: The problem with this is that it is hopelessly inefficient in the sense that ALL the recycled views will have to be redrawn.

Comment: pskink so I should add a `<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_pressed_holo_light" android:state_selected="true"/>` to my state list drawable.

Answer (score 1):

Try with a custom adapter this also helps you to have full control over your items and set a default item selected; listView XML and item XML have no special setup. Using getViewTypeCount() and selectedViewType is the key to avoid recycling your views.

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyObj> {

private final int layoutInflater;
private Context context;
private  List<MyObj> items;
private int mSelectedItem = 0;
private int TAG_UNSELECTED = 0;
private int TAG_SELECTED = 1;

public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<MyObj> items) {
    super(context, resource, items);
    this.context = context;
    this.layoutInflater = resource;
    this.items = items;
}

public void selectItem(int position) {
    mSelectedItem = position;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position == mSelectedItem ? TAG_SELECTED : TAG_UNSELECTED;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(layoutInflater, null);
    }

    MyObj myObj = items.get(position);
    TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
    textView.setText(myObj.title);

    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    if(type == TAG_SELECTED) {
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1da7ff"));
        textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    } else {
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f8f8f8"));
        textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#474747"));
    }

    return v;
}

}
```

Then in your activity:

```
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
            ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(mContext, R.layout.item_layout, list);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.selectItem(0); // Default selected item

            // Get selected item and update its background
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                    adapter.selectItem(position);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

its so easy my friend go to [this site](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) and you will find your answer.

change the color of an item when clicked and even the color of the text inside the listview

Comment: Thats only for hover.I want it to remain selected.